# Sending multiple emails (possibly any multiple steps?) inside an if block

Tags: 2010, workflow, conditional

Trying to send two emails to two different groups once a certain test passes.  If emails should be sent, send to group one - if a second test passes, send to second group.

I have it set up like so:

[image]

The issue is, whether I put the second conditional first or second, only the first email gets sent.

It's not an else clause, because you may have a situation where both emails are sent.

Is there's some rule of which I'm unaware that only allows one email to be sent in a conditional block?  Is there a way or a need (not that I see how) to make that second if a "then if" to make clear both steps need running? Is there a more explicit "brackets" construct that I need? I'm assuming that everything in the indented section should be done, but does sending an email automatically escape out?

Guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have your logic as follows

```
If condition1 is true then
    send an email to the first group
If condition2 is true then
    send an email to the second group
```

You need to have simple if condition to send an email when it matches.

Answer (score 0):

The option with no If clause of its own needed no test other than the original "if modified by" test. But I gave it a "if 1=1" so it had its own, and both emails send if required.

[image]

That was quick!